# UIViewController as a subview for other view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

My app has a menu button which is available in every view controller. Every time a user taps on the menu button, a small menu pops up. The menu has multiple `UIButton`s, and each button links to another view controller.

My current solution is to create a view controller with a nib for the menu view and add it as a subview to each of the other main view controllers.

Is there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways of doing it and I don't think there is the best answer.

However, in the performance perspective, implementing a view container such as UINavigationController or UITabBarController would be most effective.

Implement a root view controller (whose view is added as the only direct subview of the application window), and add the menu as a subview of its view. Let the root view controller decide (or know) which view to display, and add the view as a subview of its view, *below* the menu.

In this way, the view for the menu need not be removed and added again to the current view hierarchy.